# Use Python to Accumulate Values in Certain Columns with Timestamp Basis?

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a large text file, looks like in the following format:

```
89703   71.839532000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201    1514    1500    1448
89704   71.840310000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201    1514    1500    1448
89707   71.902452000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201    1514    1500    1448
89708   71.943320000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201    1514    1500    1448
89720   72.050930000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201    1514    1500    1448
89722   72.051725000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201    1514    1500    1448
89723   72.067882000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201    1514    1500    1448
89724   72.153261000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201    1514    1500    1448
89725   72.290161000    192.168.0.24    10.0.0.5        52222   5201       0
```

The second column means timestamp (e.g. 71.839532000 second), the sixth to eighth columns are the data output which was happened at that time.

I want to write a script to calculate how much data has been used in every 0.1 second period for the sixth column to the eighth column. For example, from 71.80000s to 71.899999s, the total value of the sixth, seventh and eighth column is 3028 (1514+1514), 3000 (1500+1500) and 2896 (1448+1448) respectively.

The output will look something like that:

```
71.8 3028 3000 2896
71.9 3028 3000 2896
72.0 4512 4500 4344
72.1 1514 1500 1448
72.2 0    0    0
```

How to achieve it with python? If it is not achievable, what language can we use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First I converted your sample data to csv just to make it easier to deal with. (You can still use tab separation but I think it converted it to spaces in stack overflow)
- I also added a header

```
a,timestamp,ip,ip2,b,c,data,d,e
89703,71.839532000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,1514,1500,1448
89704,71.840310000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,1514,1500,1448
89707,71.902452000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,1514,1500,1448
89708,71.943320000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,1514,1500,1448
89720,72.050930000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,1514,1500,1448
89722,72.051725000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,1514,1500,1448
89723,72.067882000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,1514,1500,1448
89724,72.153261000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,1514,1500,1448
89725,72.290161000,192.168.0.24,10.0.0.5,52222,5201,0
```

Then I used pandas, which is a popular data processing library in python.

1. read the data as a csv
2. convert the timestamp column from number (float) to timestamp (datetime)
3. group by timestamps 100 microseconds (0.1 seconds), sum, and select data column

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("sample_data.tsv")
data.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp, unit='ms')
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='100U')).sum()["data"]
```

Output

```
timestamp
1970-01-01 00:00:00.071800    3028
1970-01-01 00:00:00.071900    3028
1970-01-01 00:00:00.072000    4542
1970-01-01 00:00:00.072100    1514
1970-01-01 00:00:00.072200       0
```

The other data is there too.

```
>>> data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='100U')).sum()
                                 a       b      c  data       d       e
timestamp
1970-01-01 00:00:00.071800  179407  104444  10402  3028  3000.0  2896.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.071900  179415  104444  10402  3028  3000.0  2896.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.072000  269165  156666  15603  4542  4500.0  4344.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.072100   89724   52222   5201  1514  1500.0  1448.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.072200   89725   52222   5201     0     0.0     0.0
```

This can be written to csv using pandas as well.

Edit: I had the variable name `a` when coding up the snippet, then changed it to `data` when posting.

Comment: I got: NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: As with many answers here, the programs may not be ready-to-run, but sketches to show you how such a thing can be done. You will likely need to do a little modification to fit your problem.

Comment: It works now. But can we not alter the time format?

Comment: What time format would you like? When you output the csv, you can change the time format back into what you had before.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty straightforward use of a tool like `awk`. You should be able to pick out the second column, bucket it by the interval you want, and keep a running sum of the 6th and 8th columns per bucket. Something like (and I haven't run this, so you will likely need to edit):

```
awk '{ sums[int($2 / 0.01)] += $6 } END { for (bucket in sums) { printf "%f sum = %f\n", bucket, sums[bucket] } }' < your_file
```

Comment: I got: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Oops, you'll need another single quote before the first curly brace. I've updated the answer.